# How to generate .csd.cs file to access Custom element in web.config

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In my code, I have custom element in web.config. To access that i saw a model in a file with .csd.cs extension which was generated by a tool.Its an old code base. I need to know how it got generated. What tool we need to use to generate this file?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: In web.config, we can use custom element ex: <MySection>. To read that , we have a class file with extension .csd.cs. In this file, it is mentioned as "This file is generated by Tool". We dont know what tool it is. How to generate this .csd.cs file?

Answer (score 0):

I think config section designer is the tool you are looking for: https://github.com/hybridview/ConfigurationSectionDesigner

Might help if you are dealing with a legacy project, but I think you should consider integrating generated sections into your source and remove dependency on the extension.